# Enable/ Control script on game object from animator controller in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create an analog glitch effect in unity for may main camera when my game character/ camera looks at a certain object.

I have seen it in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LihEW5a1Tjw&t=230s) youtube video, but the part I am struggling with was not explained.

I am using this Glitch `.unitypackage` from Github ([link](https://github.com/keijiro/KinoGlitch/blob/master/KinoGlitch.unitypackage)).

I attached the `AnalogGlitch` Script from the package to my main camera game object, but this will apply the glitch effect the entire time.

[image]

Instead I want to enable the glitch effect when my character/ camera faces this certain object. I have a working animator controller, which enters a "facing state" when my camera looks at the object and a "Not facing state" when looking somewhere else (as seen in the next image).

[image]

Ideally I would just enable/ disable the `AnalogGlitch.cs` Script from my main camera game objects when this animation starts. I tried setting up a `EnableGlitch.cs` script for this, but it will not let me reference any game object in my scene. What am I doing wrong?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnableGlitch : StateMachineBehaviour
{
    public GameObject maincamera;
    override public void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        //maincamera.GetComponent<AnalogGlitch>().enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Also is there a better way to control the `AnalogGlitch.cs` script from the animator controller? I would also like to control the variables within this script to modify the effect while in this animation state.

Comment: Why do you need an animator for this? If there is no specific reason for using the animator, you can just define a new boolean value (that you change accordingly whether or not the char is looking at the object) in your character controller script and change the `<AnalogGlitch>().enabled` according to this boolean value.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot. I had not thought about it before and it works well :-)

Comment: Glad to help, good luck further :)